# Methyl Orange & Sodium bicarbonate

Tags: acid-base

I found a old bottle of methyl orange in my microscope kit, in solid form. I added water to it to form methyl orange solution. I tried putting 2 drops of methyl orange on a spot plate, then adding sodium bicarbonate. I got pink foam, which is not what i expected, as methyl orange is suppose to turn yellow on sight of a base. Does anyone know what this "methyl orange" might be instead of methyl orange? This did come from the manufacturer of the microscope kit, which has a label saying Methyl Orange, so I am confused on why it does not act as an indicator. It was originally in the kit to act as a dye for biological samples.

Comment: mightve been oxidised due to exposure , since you mentioned its old.

Comment: @Supernova In some dye collections, the samples of methyl orange, kept in glass jars, and hence maybe exposed to a little of air, are decades old and still work fairly good as pH indicator.

Comment: "Formation of foam" upon addition of NaHCO3, a weak base, may be indicative for the liberation of CO2.  Methyl orange is a sulfonate dye, i.e. an acid, and could ‒ if not delivered as a sodium salt ‒ in principle trigger the decomposition of NaHCO3.  But its solubility in water is rather low and I assume your freshly prepared solution was a diluted, one, too. (Which colour spot?) That it is sometimes intentionally mixed with xylene cyanol (https://en.wikipedia.or/wiki/Methyl_orange)  doesn't match with your likely addition of a lot of  NaHCO3  (compared to the number of molecules of dye), too.

Comment: so is this because it is old?